# Unable to initialize a TriMat matrix from the SPRS library

Tags: syntax, rust, type-inference

I am trying to use the sparse matrix library SPRS and am having trouble initializing a matrix. Why does this not work?

```
extern crate sprs;
use sprs::TriMat;

fn main() {
    let mut matrix = TriMat::new((5, 5));
}
```

The error is

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
 --> src/main.rs:5:22
  |
5 |     let mut matrix = TriMat::new((5, 5));
  |         ----------   ^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for `N`
  |         |
  |         consider giving `matrix` a type
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to tell it the type of the elements of the matrix. For example, if it's a matrix of `i32` then:

```
let mut matrix: TriMat<i32> = TriMat::new((5, 5));
```

This can't be inferred from the `new` constructor because that only takes an argument for the *shape* of the matrix, which doesn't include elements of the element type.

If you actually start storing data in the matrix, then the type annotation mostly won't be necessary because it will be inferred from the data:

```
let mut matrix = TriMat::new((5, 5));
matrix.add_triplet(0, 0, 42); // 42 literal is `i32` by default.
```

Answer (score 1):

[`TriMat`](https://docs.rs/sprs/0.6.2/sprs/type.TriMat.html) is:

```
type TriMat<N> = TriMatI<N, usize>;
```

[`TriMatI`](https://docs.rs/sprs/0.6.2/sprs/type.TriMatI.html) is:

```
type TriMatI<N, I> = TriMatBase<Vec<I>, Vec<N>>;
```

[`TriMatBase`](https://docs.rs/sprs/0.6.2/sprs/struct.TriMatBase.html) is:

```
pub struct TriMatBase<IStorage, DStorage> { /* fields omitted */ }
```

[`TriMatBase::new`](https://docs.rs/sprs/0.6.2/sprs/struct.TriMatBase.html#method.new) is:

```
pub fn new(shape: (usize, usize)) -> TriMatI<N, I>
```

Putting those together, you are effectively calling

```
TriMatBase::<_, usize>::new((5, 5));
```

The first type parameter is undecidable based on the code you've provided. In many cases, you do *something* with the value which will allow the compiler to pin down the concrete type. Since you just construct it and throw it away, there's a theoretical infinite number of types this could end up being.

You need to specify the type using the *turbofish*:

```
TriMat::<usize>::new((5, 5));
```

Or an explicit type on the variable:

```
let matrix: TriMat<usize> = TriMat::new((5, 5));
```

Or write some more code that will force the compiler to know the concrete type.